# How to convert my python file into an int?

Tags: python-3.x

the program is supposed to double the number of the player with a 75% chance and decrease by 1 with a 25% chance. If a new player receives a higher score than the last player, save the players name along with score to the file. The program exits once a player loses 5 points.

```
import random

points = 1
play = "yes"
name = input("what is your name?")
counter = 0
while play.lower() == "yes":
    risk = random.randint(0,3)
    play = input(name.upper() + "!...want to risk it to bisk it?")
    if risk == 0:
        points -= 1
        counter += 1
        if counter == 5:
            break
    else:
        points *= 2
    fi = open("score.txt", "r")
    score = fi.readlines()
    fi.close()
    scores = int(score[0])
    if (scores > points):
        fi = open("score.txt","w")
        fi.write(points + ":" + name)
        fi.close()
    print(score)
```

On the bottom is the text file "score.txt" which has the following:

```
0:No Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean read the data back in as an usable int?

```
with open('score.txt') as F:
    scores = F.readlines()
    scores = [s.strip().split(':') for s in scores]
```

Now if you want to loop through the scores data:

```
for score, name in scores:
    print(f"{name} scored:\t {int(score)}")
```